# chrome debugger api cookie sizes

Tags: api, google-chrome, debugging, cookies, size

I am making a Chrome extension. I want to get the size of cookies in bytes, similar to what the Chrome devtools -> application -> Cookies displays.

I get the cookies from Chrome using:

```
//...
if (chrome.cookies) {
chrome.cookies.getAll({url: hostname}, function(cookies) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(cookies[i], null, 1));
        }
    });
}
```

The cookies display correctly (example) :

```
{
 "domain": "REDACTED",
 "expirationDate": REDACTED,
 "hostOnly": REDACTED,
 "httpOnly": REDACTED,
 "name": "REDACTED",
 "path": REDACTED
 "sameSite": "REDACTED",
 "secure": REDACTED,
 "session": REDACTED,
 "storeId": "REDACTED",
 "value": "REDACTED"
}
```

There is no size property.

While the debugger API's Cookie object is supposed to show size, that property is not available. I am guessing this is reasonable since the Cookie object is marked experimental.
https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Network/

Based on internet search, I tried to get cookie size using

```
encodeURIComponent(cookie.value).length;
```

However this seems to return a few bytes more or less as compared to the Chrome devtools application -> cookies tab.

Is there a way I can get cookie byte size which matches devtools results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the same size of the cookie, as displayed by DevTools, use the same calculations as [the Chromium backend is using](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/devtools/protocol/network_handler.cc?type=cs&l=149):

```
(…)
.SetSize(cookie.Name().length() + cookie.Value().length())
(…)
```

In JS that would be `name.length + value.length`.

As far as I can see you shouldn't use `encodeURIComponent`:
[image: encodeURICOmponent('test<>').length]

Also, consider using [chrome.cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) API instead of the debugger protocol. The former is stable, the latter, as you already noted, has experimental parts and may change anytime.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for answering the question and providing a pointer to the chromium backend code. I did not know they had a nice interface to search through the code.

Comment: @benp12345 glad I was able to help! Regarding cs.chromium.org - I wish github had this kind of search :(